# How to add dynamically v-model and it's initial values to existed html elements by vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

For SEO purposes I need to render html elements by php. For example I have these elements.

```
<?php foreach ($elements as $key => $element): ?>
    <select name="first" v-model="model[<?= $key; ?>]">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Some Text</option>
        <option value="2">Some Text</option>
    </select>
    <select name="second" v-model="model[<?= $key; ?>]>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="4">Some Text</option>
        <option value="5">Some Text</option>
    </select>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <select name="eleven" v-model="model[<?= $key; ?>]>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="101">Some Text</option>
        <option value="102">Some Text</option>
    </select>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And probably I can manipulate these elements like this on vue side.

```
const count_models = <?= count($elements) ?>; // in the html
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    model:[]
  },
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.model);
    for (let $i = 0; $i < count_models; $i++) {
        this.model[$i] = "";
    }
  }
})
```

I cannot declare the initial values for model[?]. I need an xhr or assign counted items to a javascript variable to get how many select element I have on DOM and to declare initial values as null for each model[]. Even I redeclare the initial values of the models, it doesn't bind. I just put an example on jsFiddle. In Angular1 there was ng-init attribute to declare initial value for the model.

How can I solve this problem ?

https://jsfiddle.net/ks7jmgwv/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just encountered one of the most common gotchas of Vuejs: reactivity (and therefor the lack off)!

The issue here is when the model property is created it's just an empty array/object and any property that you add to that element it's not going to be reactive: that means any kind of change made programmatically won't trigger the Vue's internal whatches, the only reason that the v-model still works is that the changes made by the user and not by the code does actually trigger native HTML events.

You have two possible solutions:

- Ignore the reactivy part (but you won't be able to programmatically update the selected value, or at least it won't be visible) and just make sure that the 'Select' option will be selected by default by assigning it the correct value (in that way you can just skip all the default for-loop initialization).

  `<option :value="undefined" selected="selected" disabled>Select</option>`
- Follow the offical way suggested by the Vuejs' documentation to add a new property to an object and still having the advantage of reactivity

  `this.$set(this.model, $i, "");`

You can check this plunker in which I'm showing you both the ways of obtaining your goal:
https://jsfiddle.net/8y7eu39z/18/

Also, did you know that for placeholder options in a select you can add the attribute disabled?

Reactivy Reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

---

Also: if you want a "null" as a default value but did not manage to find a way to make it being recognized by the "select" options just use `:value="null"` instead of `value="null"` and then you should be able to use
`this.$set(this.model, $i, null);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Probably best option is using JQuery and manually binding changes to elements in this situations. I don't want to make xhr call or assign a value to js variable by php. I wish search engines would crawl elements which are created by js.

Comment: I'm probably missing something because I didn't get the reason behind the "better using jQuery".
But if in the AngularJS case ng-init would have be en optimal, maybe you can obain the same result by creating a similar directive yourself: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

Comment: NgInit doesn’t seem a good practice according to documentation. I used angular1 years ago and it had many problems. How can you implement a directive solution over this select example? If you show an example I will be grateful

Comment: I said that best option is probably jQuery because selecting elements and Dom manipulation is easy in jQuery and it is browser optimised for cross browser issues. I am not sure that vue or it's compiler has optimise abilities as jQuery.

Comment: The point with VueJS and AngularJS, I guess, is actually avoiding anarchy on direct and uncontrolled DOM manipulation.

Here you go the directive: 
https://jsfiddle.net/y69e0wtd/27/

Also please note: i removed the v-model and replaced it with what it has underneath because the v-model did not like, at all, the fact that you used it on undefined properties. There were errors in the console and I had to manually handle the "detail" property of the input event.